Force if-else curly braces formatting with code analyzers
I'm trying to force a specific C# code style for if-else statements in my team that has employees using different IDEs (e.g. Visual Studio, Rider etc.). This style may seem a bit weird but has already spread out through the codebase and generates a lot of noise in PR's from team members who have autoformatting enabled in their IDEs.
Basically what I'm looking for is the following:
if (condition)
{
    SomeLongMultilineMethodCall(
        param1,
        param2,
        ...);
}
else
    SomeShortMethodCall();

Here multiline if statement (even if it is a single expression) is wrapped with braces but no braces used for remaining else statement as it is single line.
I've looked through all popular roslyn analyzer libraries including StyleCop.Analyzers, Roslynator with its RCS1002 rule and even ReSharper, but none of them seem to be flexible enough. Is anyone aware of the way to automate this code style, or am I missing something?

Do you mean you want it styled like this or do you want this to be found and changed?

Honestly one reason I advocate turning off most auto-formatting (on save) in larger teams. The amount of "noise" it causes in source control is more distracting than dealing with slightly different coding formatting or the odd variation. If someone is writing in a way that is difficult to read then bring it up with them or within the team to build a consensus. I'd much rather see the odd (minor) inconsistency than sifting through formatting changes in changesets. Best of luck finding something that works across all tools.

@Fildor, I want it styled like this and all other variations should be highlighted as invalid by roslyn analyzer or some other code analysis tool.

@StevePy I agree with you on this, but I don't need something that works across all tools  if I can force check this style in CI/CD pipeline and reject PR's with inconsistent formatting.

" and reject PR's with inconsistent formatting" - you'll be the hero of the team -- NOT. Do not do this. It is a bad idea. The format may be a matter of opinion (and I'd never  agree to that) but enforcing it in CI/CD with auto-reject will put a cross-hair on your back.

Roslyn analyzers are the best way to stay independent from IDE and to integrate this check into your CI/CD pipeline. I don't think you can your requirements fully covered, so the closest solution you can get is using Roslynator. Try to set severity=warning to the following rules:

RCS1001 - forces braces for multiline expressions
RCS1002 - removes braces from single line expressions
RCS1004 - removes braces from if-else when possible

